# How can I replace all regex matches using the WP_CLI search-replace tool

Tags: wp-cli

With [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) I can use the [search-replace](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) method like this:

`wp search-replace 'foo' 'bar'`

However, when I use regex, it only replaces the *first* occurrence within each DB field:

`wp search-replace 'myRegex' 'bar' --regex`

In the above example, only the first regex match for `myRegex` is replaced in any given DB field. I can repeatedly run the search over and over until all matches have been replaced, but I'd like to be able to do it in one command. The /g global flag is not available because when I try it:

`wp search-replace 'myRegex/g' 'bar' --regex`

I get a bunch of warnings that I cannot use it with php preg_replace:

> PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: You could ask on their GitHub https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, WP-CLI uses `preg_replace()` to perform the regex search-replace operation. By default, `preg_replace()` is a global operation. If WP-CLI is only replacing the first instance, there may be some other issue at hand.

If you've found a bug though, and can provide a test case to reproduce it, please [open an issue](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues) and we can get it fixed.