# Using wp-cli and delete everypost first image

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, wp-cli

I was change my website template then i have one problem which before used template was not have thumbnail place for post for this i add all my post first image for this now on new template showing each post two pictures.

First featured image, after what i was add image showing for this problem i wanna clear first image on all my post.

What i try,

1) Manually but my site has 40000 posts thats mean not so easy to do that on manually.

2) I try to use wp-cli then i use this code

```
wp search-replace '/<img[^>]+\>/i' '' wp_posts --regex --allow-root
```

But result is

```
+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------+
| Table    | Column                | Replacements | Type |
+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------+
| wp_posts | post_content          | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_title            | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_excerpt          | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_status           | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | comment_status        | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | ping_status           | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_password         | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_name             | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | to_ping               | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | pinged                | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_content_filtered | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | guid                  | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_type             | 0            | PHP  |
| wp_posts | post_mime_type        | 0            | PHP  |
+----------+-----------------------+--------------+------+
Success: Made 0 replacements.
```

3) I try this code on fuctions.php

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
if (!is_page() && !is_feed() && !is_feed() && !is_home()) {
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
} return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

On this solution i fix my problem but i don't want use this solution for that i'm searching any other solution with **WP-CLI**.

Comment: Is there only one image in each post or do you want to remove all images from posts?

Comment: Are you sure the `<img>` tags are in the database and not added dynamically via a plugin or so?

Comment: each post have few image i want to delete first one @kero

Comment: @swissspidy <img src="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/image.jpg" alt="" width="660" height="250" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-28061" /> like this on text editor i don't know about database

Answer (score 1):

According to the [WP-CLI docs for the `wp search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) (and `wp db search`, for that matter), you have to pass your search string without delimiters and pass any flags separately.

Instead of:

```
wp search-replace '/<img[^>]+\>/i' '' wp_posts --regex --allow-root
```

You would use something more like this:

```
wp search-replace '<img[^>]+\>' '' wp_posts --regex --allow-root --regex-flags='i' --regex-delimiter='/'
```

I just tested this on an install and I'm getting plenty of results.

**Edit**: WP-CLI indeed does not yet support some sort of limit parameter to only replace the first occurrence. However, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/wp-cli/search-replace-command/issues/61) for it so it might be possible in the future.

Comment: This delete all image on post not first one

Comment: @ZgrKARALAR You can try to use the question mark regex flag so the search is non-greedy, i.e. `…regex-flags=i?`

Comment: Error: The regex '/<img[^>]+\>/i?' fails.

Comment: Ah right, my bad. I mixdd things up. `--regex-flags='iU'` should work in PHP.

Comment: @swisspidy same problem as first deleting all image on post not first

Comment: I just checked the source code of WP-CLI and also [this similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213660/how-can-i-replace-all-regex-matches-using-the-wp-cli-search-replace-tool) — it seems that because WP-CLI doesn't set the limit parameter of [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), it _always_ replaces all occurrences. After all, that's what the tool was made for.

Comment: Raised an issue with WP-CLI: https://github.com/wp-cli/search-replace-command/issues/61.